# how to get the data using Joins or Cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have requirement

sample data : 
Table A :

```
ID  name
1   cat
2   Dog
3   Bird
```

Table B :

```
ID  name
1   aaa
1   bbb
2   ccc
2   ddd
```

Table C :

```
ID  name
1   xxx
1   yyy
1   zzz
2   www
```

Required Output :

```
ID  name    name    name
1   cat aaa xxx
1   cat bbb yyy
1   cat null    zzz
2   Dog ccc www
2   Dog ddd www
3   Bird    NULL    NULL
```

I have tried with different joins

```
Select a.ID,a.name,b.name,c.name from @A a
full join @b b
on   a.ID = b.ID 
full join @c c
on   b.ID = c.ID
```

Can anyone suggest me the best way to Proceed?

Comment: What's the logic behind it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Explain the logic behind your output. Also, please understand that there is no implicit order of rows in RDBMS.

Comment: I'm unable to get the logic that's the reason I have posted here and more over I have clearly given the data and output. I asked for suggestion

Comment: The desired output is very strange, as it suggests that aaa and xxx are somewhat related while aaa and yyy are not. I would ask the person who asked you to write the query why is that. A more reasonable output might be one row per animal with concatenated strings 'aaa, bbb' and 'xxx, yyy, zzz'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use window function `row_number` to assign sequence number within each `id` in the order of increasing `name` for table `b` and `c` and then do a full join between them. Finally, do a left join with `a` table:

```
with b1 as (
    select b.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as rn
    from b
    ),
c1 as (
    select c.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as rn
    from c
    )
select a.*, t.b_name, t.c_name
from a
left join (
    select coalesce(b1.id, c1.id) as id,
        b1.name as b_name,
        c1.name as c_name
    from b1
    full join c1 on b1.id = c1.id
        and b1.rn = c1.rn
    ) t on a.id = t.id;
```

This assumes that you need to join the tables `b` and `c` based on id and the position (in the order of `name` column).

Comment: perfect fulfill the need

Comment: Perhaps this is the only reason, reading Stack Overflow is more useful than wasting time of Facebook. @GurV, Can you please explain a bit more about the logic you used here. I also need to implement the same logic in my project also. Tonnes of thanks in advance.